# Add a new button in payment page prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am new in Prestashop
I want to add a button to the part I specified in
the attached image. Does anyone know how to do this?
Which tpl file do I need to include the button code?
version 1.7.2.5

[attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgyZK.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find this around the line number 122 of file `/themes/classic/templates/checkout/_partials/steps/payment.tpl`